# How to avoid Buffered Reader to hang Android App? Java/Python

Tags: java, android, python, sockets

I'm currently developing an Android App which needs to comunicate via sockets. The server socket is on Python. I am able to send messages and read them on python server, but when I try to send a message from server to App the App hangs and stop working (I pretty sure on the `bufferedread.realine()`). 
The method I'm using is the `sendMessage` which returns a `String` that reads from the `InputStream` but it actually hangs when trying to do that. How can I fix this?
Thanks BTW

PYTHON SERVER CODE

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
import threading
import os

global init,userCount
puerto = 999
init = False
userCount = 0
def setupServer():
    global server,init
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        print("PUERTO: "+str(puerto))
        server.bind(('', puerto))
        init = True
        server.listen(5)
    except:
        print("Failed to create socket")

def listen():
    global server,init,userCount
    if(init == True):
        print("- Server Initialized -")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        userCount+=1
        print("**User Connected**" + " User:"+str(userCount))
        b= Thread(target=handleClient, args=(conn,addr))
        b.daemon = True
        b.start()
        b.join()
        if(userCount == 0):
            break
        server.close()
    print("- Server Closed -")
def handleClient(conn,addr):
    global userCount
    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        data = data.decode("utf-8")
        try:
            if(data != ""):
                if(data == "exit\n"):
                    break
                message = "Received\n"
               conn.send(message)
               print(data)

        except:
            pass
    userCount-=1
setupServer()
listen()
```

CLASS OF SOCKET AT ANDROID APP

```
public class SocketClient implements Runnable {
    private Socket socket;
    public PrintWriter mBufferOut;
    private BufferedReader mBufferIn;

    public SocketClient(String pAdress, int pPort) {

        try {
            socket = new Socket(pAdress, pPort);

            try {
                mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);
            }

        }catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

        }
    }

    public String sendMessage(String message) {
        if (mBufferOut != null && !mBufferOut.checkError()) {
            mBufferOut.println(message);
            try {
                if(mBufferIn.ready() == true){
                    String line;
                    if((line = mBufferIn.readLine()) != null){
                        return line;
                    }
                    else{
                        return "NULL";
                    }

                }
                else{
                    return "NOT READY";
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return "ERROR";
    }

    public void closeConnection(){
        try {
            socket.close();
        }catch (IOException e){
            Log.e("TCP Client", "Error");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say it stops working is it crashing or hanging? Is there any output in Logcat? Stops working is a very broad statement.

Comment: It seems `SocketClient()` method is operated in `Main thread` that handles Android UI. So if your try to use `Socket` connection like that, it will be stuck. I recommend to use `Thread` or `AsyncTask`. It makes your socket connection operates asynchronously, and avoid hanging.

Comment: Maybe it's a stupid question, but have you added line breaks to messages sent to your client? Because BufferedReader get stuck if it don't find any of these characters (\n or \r)

Comment: -By stops working I mean I get the Message "Unfortunaly App has stopped"....
-SocketClient is not working in the main thread, I actually created a new thread from an AsyncTask, and if I just send messages from App to server it works great.
-Im also sending (\n and \r) from the server each time I send a message